# Report Rsquare and Standard Error SAS under PROC MODEL and SUR

Tags: sas, stat, proc

If I run a simple `proc reg` in SAS, I have no problem to report the standard errors and rsquare. But why am I having some difficulties to report the Rsquare and Standard Errors for the intercepts and coefficients under this `PROC MODEL`setup?

```
proc model data=have;
var r1-3;
parms a1-a10 b1-b10;
r1=a1+b1*A+b4*B+b7*C; 
r2=a2+b2*A+b5*B+b8*C;
r3=a3+b3*A+b6*B+b9*C; 
fit r1-r3/sur outs=want outest=est;
test a1, a2, a3,/wald;
run;
```

where can I type `OUTSEB` and `RSQUARE` so the results can be reported in the `est` dataset? I've tried to type `OUTSEB` and `RSQUARE` after `OUTEST` or after `proc model data=have` etc... no success.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but have you read the documentation for `PROC MODEL`?  Each SAS procedure is different; you can't just "try" option names.  The docs are very good, just make sure to read the ones for your specific version of SAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FSRSQ` gives you the R2. It can be used as an option in both the `PROC MODEL` and `FIT` statements (if you use it in the former, it will become default for all subsequent `FIT` statements).

```
proc model fsrsq ...
```